# Field Reference error inVisualforce Email Template

Tags: soql, email, error, fields, reference

i tried to create an email template with a generated attachement. All is good, but i have a probem with one field...

My table User, have a field ManagerId, who is a reference.
I need to get the name of the manager.

On the IDE, i can get it by `"Manager.Name"`, but in my visualforce page, if i write `"{!$User.Manager.Name}"`, i get this error :

> "Error: Unable to access the following field: Manager.Name. Contact
>   the administrator."

I join my two screenshot, thanks for your help :)

[image: My Table User, my query and the result]

[image: My error :(]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not access User Manager name but you can access ManagerId {!$User.ManagerId}

To access the name you can create a custom formula field on User object. Set it return type text and use  `Manager.FirstName`.

Reference that field it in Visualforce page

Comment: Thanks ! It Work Perfectly :) I create two custom fields, one for the first name and the other one for the last name ;)